# Why the hash value is undefined?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bcrypt

Value of salt is logged correctly but hash is giving undefined.
I am unable to figure out what is incorrect here.
users.js is a model and the other code is a controller.
users.js

```
    UserSchema.statics.updateOTPOnDatabase = function(mobile,otp){             
            bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){            
                         console.log(salt);          //this works fine                                               
               bcrypt.hash(otp, salt, function(err, hash){                                                                                        
                         console.log(hash);        //giving undefined                        
               });        
            })              
    }
```

login.js

```
exports.login = (req, res) => {
    const mobile = _.pick(req.body, ['mobile_number']);

    User.findByMobile(mobile).then((user) => {
        const otp = Math.round(Math.random()*9000 + 1000);
        User.updateOTPOnDatabase(user.mobile_number, otp).then(res => {
            console.log(res);

         }).catch(err => {
             var response = {
                 status: 'failure',
                 message: err.message
             };
             res.send(response);
        });

    }).catch(err => {
        var response = {
            status: 'failure',
            message: err.message
        }
        res.send(response);
    });

};
```

Comment: `console.log(err);`

Comment: The error showing up - Error: Illegal arguments: number, string

Comment: That probably means `bcrypt.hash` expect the first parameter `otp` to be `String`, but you  pass a `Number`

Comment: making otp = otp.toString() solved it. Thanks guys for ur time!!

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can see is with your `updateOTPOnDatabase` function, as in this function you are accepting 1 parameter `otp` but when you call this function you are passing 2 parameters `user.mobile_number,otp`

This is your definition

```
UserSchema.statics.updateOTPOnDatabase = function(otp){ }
```

This is how you are invoking it

```
User.updateOTPOnDatabase(user.mobile_number, otp) { }
```

So you might need to fix 1 or the other and also check if `user.mobile_number` is not returning `undefined` or `null`

**Edit 2**

As per the comment and per [Github code](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/blob/4adc3869a9a97f73aa3858a7ead575196b17a22f/bcrypt.js#L109), a string is expected so you can convert `otp` to string by using `.toString()` method

```
UserSchema.statics.updateOTPOnDatabase = function(mobile,otp){             
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){            
                     console.log(salt);                                                         
           bcrypt.hash(otp.toString(), salt, function(err, hash){                                                                                        
                     console.log(hash);                       
           });        
        })              
}
```